# Not able to start firefox for protractor automation angular 2 + angular cli

Tags: protractor, angular-cli, angular2-testing, geckodriver

I am using the following npm command to run the automation tests.

```
    webdriver-manager clean && webdriver-manager update && ng e2e
```

I have firefox as one of my multiCapabilities for protractor.conf.js.

But I could not able to launch firefox. It is throwing the following error.

`[17:37:20] E/launcher - Unable to parse new session response: {"value": {"sessionId":"389d1b05-d48b-3e4d-8ba6-a763a75f6719","value":{"acceptInsecureCerts":false,"browserName":"firefox","browserVersion":"52
.0.2","moz:accessibilityChecks":false,"moz:processID":8904,"moz:profile":"/var/folders/md/9vtqtrxs4f52kl2dsymc5w1mjn7g_z/T/rust_mozprofile.LeFhKUQqBlZN","pageLoadStrategy":"normal","platformName":"darwin",
"platformVersion":"15.6.0","rotatable":false,"specificationLevel":0,"timeouts":{"implicit":0,"page load":300000,"script":30000}}}}`

Note: I am using 'directConnect:true' in configuration.
If I use 'directConnect:false', I am getting geckodriver path error in console which I need to set it manually. I was expecting angular-cli will take care of it automatically which doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are DirectConnect "issues" with Firefox, see also [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4182). 
Secondly there is a "bug" in the GekoDriver, see [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/515)

Hope it helps answering your question